# Debian 7.2 - Adding links to desktop

Tags: debian

I would like to add a link to the desktop using Debian 7.2 with Gnome.

I have put a link into /home/desktop however it doesn't show on the desktop.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: How are you currently placing the icon on the desktop? Do you receive any errors or notifications?

Comment: No I just can't find a way to do it. I tried dragging links onto the desktop and it doesn't do anything, I tried creating links in /home/desktop and it doesn't show on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The desktop and right click is disabled in Gnome 3. However you can activate it with the following instruction:

[Link](http://joesteiger.com/2011/07/02/enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-gnome-3-gnome-shell-ubuntu-11-04/)